# Running multiple webpack dev servers in the same host

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Currently I am running a webpack dev server on the localhost port 3000 for one UI project

```
webpack-dashboard -- webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --watch --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000
```

Now when I want to run another webpack dev server on the localhost port 4000 for another UI project it throws `EADDRINUSE` error because webpack-dev-server is bound to first UI project in port 3000

How do I configure webpack-dev-server to run both UI projects simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out webpack-dashboard does not allow more than one webpack-dev-server to run. I am now running webpack-dev-server without passing it to webpack-dashboard like below

`webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --watch --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000`